# awk command inside while loop creates empty output files

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

I am trying to loop through the lines of a file (Names.txt) and looking for the expressions of each line on another file (Data.txt). I want to print the lines of Data.txt containing one expression on a file line.txt. Say my file Names.txt looks like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

And my file Data.txt looks like this:

```
A    info1
D    info2
C    info3
B    info4
E    info5
F    info6
```

I used the following command directly on Terminal (Mac OSX):

```
while read line; do awk '/$line/ { print $0 }' Data.txt > $line.txt; done < Names.txt
```

Though all the files $line.txt are created, they are unfortunately all empty. It seems to be an error with my use of the while loop, since when I only put the awk command to look for a single expression it works just fine...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
awk '/$line/ { print $0 }' Data.txt
```

With:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$0 ~ line { print $0 }' Data.txt
```

The problem is that `line` is a shell variable.  The top line has `$line` inside of *single*-quotes.  The shell won't touch anything inside single-quotes.  So, the `print` statement is only executed if the line matches a literal dollar sign followed by `l`, `i`, `n`, and `e`.

In the second version above, the `-v` option is used to create an `awk` variable called `line`.  The `awk` variable can then be used in the script.

#### Another approach, possibly dangerous

We could try to use the shell variable `line` directly by placing it in double-quotes:

```
awk "/$line/"' { print $0 }' Data.txt
```

Don't do this unless you have trust in the contents of `line`.  For example, if `line` had the following value:

```
line='./ {print "Ha Ha"} /A'
```

Then, the `awk` script would execute without error but it would do some unexpected things.  Because this can be a security issue, it is much safer to use the `awk` variable approach described above.

#### A Somewhat Cryptic Simplification

If an `awk` command has a condition but not an action, the default is `print $0`.  This means that, if you like, the `awk` command can be simplified to:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$0 ~ line' Data.txt
```

#### A Suggestion

It looks like you want to match the lines in `Names.txt` with the *first column* of `Data.txt`.  If that is the case, you may want to refine the condition to avoid false matches by using:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$1 ~ line' Data.txt
```

Comment: It works perfectly! And I understood why it was wrong, thank you very much!